# Preventing auto login to the default email on an android tablet

Tags: gmail, google-account

When using an android tablet for the first time, I have to set a default email google account.

When I click on the Gmail icon, it automatically log into my gmail account.

Is there a way to prevent the system from automatic logging in to the default gmail account by clicking on the Gmail icon.

I am seeking a way to force the system to ask for my gmail login password each time there is a try to login to my account by clicking on the gmail icon. This is to prevent anyone who could manage to use my tablet from logging in to my gmail account.

Comment: Turn off Gmail sync from settings if that's bothering you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is possible to sign out, the login will appear the next time you try to sign in like signing out from the desktop or laptop.
However, it is not possible to sign out of Gmail for Android unless you remove your account as stated in [Sign out of Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8154?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)

> The only way to sign out of the Gmail app is to remove your entire account from your phone or tablet

A possible solution to add a security layer before opening Gmail app is to install an [app lock](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=app%20lock&c=apps&authuser) from Google Play Store or any market of your preference. These apps allow to lock individual apps. You will still be login to your Gmail account but before opening the app, you will be prompted to enter a pin or pattern.